# Как избавиться от скачков текста при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, css

Беру шрифт с google fonts, при загрузке страницы сначала загружаются стандартные шрифты, а потом скачком шрифт меняется на шрифт с google.

Comment: Загрузить шрифты к себе на сервер. Подключить в шапке "критически важные" стили, включая и загрузку шрифтов. Уменьшить до необходимого минимума варианты шрифтов: языки, начертания ([Literata](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literata))

Comment: Есть свойство в css, но я забыл, какое...

Comment: Вы просто сделали так, чтобы грузился сначала контент, а потом грузился шрифт. Нужно, чтобы шрифт раньше грузился и желательно локально, не подтягивать с Google Fonts.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-best-font-loading-strategies-and-how-to-execute-them/

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего настройка шрифта указана в конце HTML формы.
Поэтому сначала браузер загружает и выполняет содержимое, а потом очередь доходит до шрифта.

Попробуйте перенести установку шрифта в блок `<head>` страницы.